# Socket.io session without Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I have app in node.js using socket.io for websockets(live chat) it runs on live-chat.dev domain.

Now i have another project runs on localhost where i'm connecting to live-chat.dev (client side).

I identify users by session.id that stores in node.js app.

The problem is : every page reloads brings new session.id generated.

config of node.js session middlware :

```
var sessionMiddleWare  = session({
  secret: 'livechat key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    domain : 'localhost'
  }
});

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleWare(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `persistent session`. You can achieve this by storing your session object in any data store and fetching it form there.

If you are comfortable with `mongodb` then you can use `connect-mongo` library.

You can read more about it here https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo

Comment: But the problem is that my apps running on different hostnames, and that is why socket io gives me new session id every time. If i run two project on one host. everything works fine

Comment: Then I think in your case you will have to write a custom middleware and handle both the domains as one. Also you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104292/express-session-with-different-cookie-domain-per-request it may help you.

Comment: it didn't helped, i think the problem is in that localhost project  doesn't set coockie when receives it. Thank you for trying to help!